# What the heck is a OPTIONS method in a IIS 7.5 web Log?

Tags: web-server, iis-7.5, log-files

I know what a GET and a POST are, but it's almost impossible to Google for the word OPTIONS.  Here's what I see (i deleted all the stuff at the end) of each:

```
11/23/11    0:02:13 10.100.0.14         GET       /CUpdate2.cshtml  _=1322006533495
11/23/11    0:02:13 10.200.0.10         OPTIONS   /AssignmentCount  _=1322006576798
11/23/11    0:02:13 10.200.0.10         GET       /media/faxSound.wav   -
11/23/11    0:02:13 10.200.0.10         GET       /Star/StarUpdates _=1322006578729
11/23/11    0:02:13 10.100.0.10         GET       /CUpdate2.cshtml  _=1322006533268
```

Comment: i know I shouldn't have put heck in my question, but what the heck is an OPTIONS!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out section 9.2 of [this W3 Spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html):

> The OPTIONS method represents a request for information about the communication options available on the request/response chain identified by the Request-URI. This method allows the client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval.

[This blog post](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2005/04/03/options) is also worth a read.

Comment: Thank you.  I vaguely knew the log was in a W3C format, and probably should have looked there.  Now the next question is, WHY is a iPad sending an OPTIONS requestion to the server?